How to configure Serilog to dynamically route logs to different files based on service context at runtime?
I use Serilog for logging, my goal is to have each service within the application write logs to a specific file based on a path parameter at runtime (I can't use this solution).
I'm configuring the Serilog to write to ElasticSearch sink (and Console), so I prefer to config my Serilog only once in the DI with:
builder.Host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(
        new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("https://esk.mycompany.com:443"))
        {
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            IndexFormat = "logs-mycompany-myservice",
            TypeName = null,
            BatchAction = ElasticOpType.Create,
            ModifyConnectionSettings = (c) =>
            {
                c.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(
                (o, certificate, arg3, arg4) => { return true; });
                c.GlobalHeaders(new NameValueCollection { { "Authorization", "ApiKey " + "..." } });
                return c;
            },                    
        }
)
.Enrich.WithElasticApmCorrelationInfo()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration)
.WriteTo.Console()
);

For example I'm trying to achieve something like:
public class ServiceA
{
    private readonly ILogger<ServiceA> _logger;

    public ServiceA(ILogger<ServiceA> logger, string pathA)
    {
        logger.SetPath(pathA) // All serviceA's logs will be saved in "pathA"
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    private readonly ILogger<ServiceB> _logger;

    public ServiceB(ILogger<ServiceB> logger, string pathB)
    {
        logger.SetPath(pathB) // All serviceB's logs will be saved in "pathB"
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

How can I inject the path in Serilog in run-time so it will still sends the logs to elasticsearch and write as well to a log file in the path?
